# VBA Excel lookup same value in different excel files

Tags: vba, excel

Would like to check the value from my master file and copy the data comments from different excel files.

In my master I have a column contained all the user name. Would like to copy the address of the user from different excel file. Would like to open the workbook and look through is the user name in the workbook, if not then then exit and open another workbook.

How should I complete the flow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Our goal is to help you understand how your code works and engage the community with questions that will also help others in the future. Try running some of the code on your own and see what you can come up with. There are hundreds of sources online, one of my favorite being "Excel Easy", a website that breaks down VBA coding to its simplest form. Check it out and then after you've given it a go yourself feel free to ask any specific question about your code!

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for the feedback, actually I done some part but now I face a problem is how can I loop through all the workbook and check the value is inside the workbook or not. BTW thanks for the excel easy. is a cool website

Comment: @JamLong No problem. Excel Easy makes it very easy to understand the basics of Macro coding. Now that you've done some work on your own, feel free to post another question asking for help with what you're stuck on. But remember before asking a question, do adequate research, someone else may have asked the same or similar question before, and be sure to be clear and concise once you decide to ask your question. You can read about how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MVCE) in the help section. Be sure to post your code and anything else you may need help with. Happy coding!

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, check the checkmark next to my answer so others will know this question is closed and they can refer to your newer questions if you have code specific questions!

Comment: Hello @JamLong can you close the question by clicking the green check mark next to the answer?